# Refactoring jQuery With a Selector and index

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

Just to get it working, I have an FAQ page with jQuery that hides all divs classed with `.faqSection`, as well as a unique id -- `#faqSection1`, `#faqSection2`, etc.  . I then go through with the Waypoint plugin that detects when the offset of a given div is at 80% of viewport.

Before refactoring, the code looks like this:

```
jQuery('.faqSection').css('opacity', 0);
jQuery('#faqSection2').waypoint(function() {
    jQuery('#faqSection2').delay(800).queue('fx', function() { jQuery(this).addClass('animated fadeInDown'); });
}, { offset: '80%' });

jQuery('#faqSection3').waypoint(function() {
    jQuery('#faqSection3').delay(800).queue('fx', function() { jQuery(this).addClass('animated fadeInDown'); });
}, { offset: '80%' });

jQuery('#faqSection4').waypoint(function() {
    jQuery('#faqSection4').delay(800).queue('fx', function() { jQuery(this).addClass('animated fadeInDown'); });
}, { offset: '80%' });

jQuery('#faqSection5').waypoint(function() {
    jQuery('#faqSection5').delay(800).queue('fx', function() { jQuery(this).addClass('animated fadeInDown'); });
}, { offset: '80%' });

jQuery('#faqSection6').waypoint(function() {
    jQuery('#faqSection6').delay(800).queue('fx', function() { jQuery(this).addClass('animated fadeInDown'); });
}, { offset: '80%' });
```

As you can see, it's just the number on the end that changes. I wanted to refactor for that very reason, plus want to accommodate a different number of divs.

So I tried this:

```
jQuery('.faqSection').css('opacity', 0);
for(var index = 0;
    index < $('.faqSection').length; index++) {
    jQuery('#faqSection' + index).waypoint(function() {
        jQuery('#faqSection' + index).delay(800).queue('fx', function() { jQuery(this).addClass('animated fadeInDown'); });
    }, { offset: '80%' });
}
```

Is it not possible to do a selector plus index, or do I have something else incorrect in my syntax and/or thinking?

Comment: It's not a huge deal, but inside your waypoint callback, why not make use of `this.element`, rather than again selecting #faqSection1 or whichever? You can even use a common handler, starting with: jQuery(this.element).delay(800).queue('fx', function() {

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a guess, but I think the issue may be that you're failing to capture the `index` variable properly. (In other words, the code inside the function always sees the latest value of `index` instead of the one at the time you set it up.)

Give this a try instead (also factoring in @Neverever's point that your index probably starts and ends at the wrong number):

```
jQuery('.faqSection').css('opacity', 0);
for(var index = 2;
    index <= $('.faqSection').length; index++) {
    (function (index) { jQuery('#faqSection' + index).waypoint(function() {
        jQuery('#faqSection' + index).delay(800).queue('fx', function() { jQuery(this).addClass('animated fadeInDown'); });
    }, { offset: '80%' }); })(index);
}
```

**EDIT**

Even better:

```
jQuery('.faqSection').css('opacity', 0);

// slice(1) skips the first element
jQuery('.faqSection').slice(1).each(function () {
    jQuery(this).waypoint(function () {
        jQuery(this).delay(800).queue('fx', function () {
            jQuery(this).addClass('animated fadeInDown');
        });
    });
});
```

Or, assuming waypoint works this way (I think most jQuery plugins do):

```
jQuery('.faqSection').css('opacity', 0);

// slice(1) skips the first element
jQuery('.faqSection').slice(1).waypoint(function () {
    jQuery(this).delay(800).queue('fx', function () {
        jQuery(this).addClass('animated fadeInDown');
    });
});
```

Comment: Note that your second snippet assumes that #faqSection1 through 6 are the only children of .faqSection.

Comment: @Aaron Yes, that's correct.

Comment: @Aaron Or rather, it assumes that `#faqSection1` through `6` are the only elements on the page that have the class `faqSection`.

Comment: Ah, right, my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

your index starts from `0`, and I assume `#faqSection0`  does not exist

the code should look like this

```
for(var index = 0; index < $('.faqSection').length; index++) {
    var faq = '#faqSection' + (index + 2);  // assuming #faqSection starts from 2
    jQuery(faq).waypoint(function() {
        jQuery(faq).delay(800).queue('fx', function() { jQuery(this).addClass('animated fadeInDown'); });
    }, { offset: '80%' });
}
```